# Платформа/подход для разработки проекта

Tags: android, c#, ios, wpf, asp

Есть VS 2015 и есть желание запилить программу, что-бы ее можно было и на компьютере использовать и на планшете и через web. Какую платформу или подход взять, что-бы не переписывать приложение несколько раз?

Comment: А какая операционка бежит на планшете? Если Win10, то UWP по идее. Если iOS/Android, то Xamarin. Но вот с web так просто не пройдёт, думаю, придётся писать что-то отдельное.

Comment: Компы Win 7-10 планшет Win10. Телефон iOS.

Comment: WPF только комп?

Comment: Боюсь, что да. Но UWP от WPF совсем рядом, можно расшарить большую часть кода.

Comment: Java решит проблему. Можно же почти везде запустить, где есть JVM

Comment: Какие широкораспространенные примеры приложений с гуем вы знаете на Java?

Comment: Вы просто так проигнорировали упоминание visual studio и c#?

Comment: Теоретически можно C++ & QT.

Comment: @cpp_user intellij idea

Comment: Для хомяков имелось ввиду.

Comment: если  "и на компьютере использовать и на планшете и через web" Да плюс ещё платформы разные (7,10, ios) А в качестве инструмента VS15 (и тег C# подразумевает предпочтительный язык, я полагаю)  тут только один универсальный вариант: ASP.net

Comment: @Alexey ну почему, вынести весь функционал в сервисы на удаленный сервер, а легких клиентов для каждой платформы сделать отдельно. Это конечно не одна софтина на всех, но наиболее работоспособный вариант. Даже Java на самом деле не дает полной кроссплатформенности, всегда остаются нюансы и часть кода приходится кастомизировать под конкретную платформу.

Comment: @rdorn: Да да, тоже как вариант. В принципе тот же С# позволяет используя WPF+UWP+Xamarin покрыть всё многообразие платформ (кроме экзотики) не сильно при этом переписывая код. 
Но в вопросе было "то-бы не переписывать приложение несколько раз",,,

Comment: Используйте Xamarin, тогда можно будет приложение запускать на всех платформах на всех девайсах (Android iOS Windows)

Answer (score 2):

Если использовать паттерн MVVM. Скажем так - в решение добавляем "Библиотеку классов". В ней мы будем хранить  Model и ViewModels. А все остальные проекты будут содержать View.

В ASP.Net вроде тоже должно сработать...

Answer (score 0):

если взаимодействие с приложением не требует сложного пользовательского интерфейса, можно запилить бота на Telegram (открытые библиотеки с API на .NET уже есть) и юзать функционал через него =)